# When inserting elements into DOM with jQuery, how do you prevent page from briefly jumping on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am moving a DIV (from a hidden iFrame) to the top of a page with jQuery, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#precontainer').clone().insertBefore(parent.document.querySelectorAll(".maincontainer"));});
```

Whenever I reload that page, I very briefly see the original page jumping down to make room for the DIV I am inserting. Can this behavior be prevented?

What I'm doing now is give the "maincontainer" a large margin at the top with CSS that is roughly as high as the "precontainer" DIV that is inserted above it, and after that DIV is inserted, I use jQuery to remove the top margin from "maincontainer", so the jumping or flashing effect is less severe. But there has to be a better way right?

I should mention that I only have access to the iFrame that I am using to manipulate the DOM of its parent (which holds "maincontainer". I can not modify the parent, so I have to do everything through the iFrame.

Comment: remove the .ready() and add the javascript code under the #precontainer html code

Comment: I modified my question to reflect the fact I can't add HTML or JS to the parent which holds the "maincontainer" (I am working with a software solution which I'm not allowed to alter directly, ony through JS/CSS).

Comment: if you remove the on document ready, it should be faster, see this http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving a top-margin to parent page, you can place a "placeholder" div and insert your "precontainer" to this div. This way you shouldn't see a flickering/jumping effect.

Comment: I should mention that I can not alter the parent in any way other than with CSS and jQuery/javascript. So unfortunately I can't add a placeholder DIV.